# WKB for $E > V(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, semiclassical

When we use the WKB method, at least when I learned it, all of our examples had $V(x) > E$ at some point, allowing for turning points.

Say we have some $V(x) < E$ for all $x$. How would we apply WKB to get a solution for our wave functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of space is classically accessible $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:E>V(x)$, then we are looking at (non-normalizable) scattering states in the continuum part of the energy spectrum, where there is no quantization condition, and where the WKB wave function for the 1D [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) is purely oscillatory
$$ \psi(x)~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{p(x)}}\sum_{\pm}C_{\pm} \exp\left(\pm \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{x_0}^x \! p(x^{\prime})~\mathrm{d}x^{\prime}\right),\qquad  p(x)~:= \sqrt{2m (E-V(x))}.$$
The two complex constants $C_{\pm}\in \mathbb{C}$ can in principle be determined from asymptotic scattering data as $x\to \pm \infty$.